# Retrieve JSON Data As NSString Not Integer?

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, nsstring, integer

The code below only works if my JSON data is a series of integers, e.g. [11,12,13]. How could I get it to retrieve a message/phrase instead?

```
- (IBAction)checkmessages:(id)sender
{
        responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];       
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/Alex/Desktop/Test.json"]];
        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {      
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

    NSError *error;
    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
    NSArray *luckyNumbers = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&error];
    [responseString release];   

    if (luckyNumbers == nil)
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"JSON parsing failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
    else {      
        NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Latest Message:\n"];

        for (int i = 0; i < [luckyNumbers count]; i++) 
            [text appendFormat:@"%@\n", [luckyNumbers objectAtIndex:i]];

        label.text =  text;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
When my JSON File looks like: [10,11,12], it works fine, but if I change it to: [Message 1,Message 2], I get the error: "JSON Parsing Failed: Expected value while parsing array"

Comment: What problem are you having? How does it fail if the JSON data comes back as a string?

Comment: When my JSON File looks like: [10,11,12], it works fine, but if I change it to: [Message 1,Message 2], I get the error: "JSON Parsing Failed: Expected value while parsing array"

Comment: I presume there is also some quotations missing, ie: ["message 1", "message 2"]

Comment: Glad it did :), I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON looks malformed,

```
 [Message 1,Message 2]
```

should be

```
 ["Message 1", "Message 2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

"Strings" in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) must be enclosed in quotes (`""`).